# EOL conversions disabled in .gitattributes only apply to new files

Tags: git, eol, gitattributes

I have disabled the automatic EOL conversion by pushing the following .gitattributes to master:

```
   # disable automatic eol conversions
   * text=false
```

After that, pushed some files on Linux and pulled the changes from a Windows machine only to discover that the line endings of the files which where not changed had been converted from \n to \r\n.

I tried:

- removing the repo and doing a git clone (on Windows)
- running the following on Linux and pushing again:

  ```
      git rm --cached -r .
      git add -A
  ```
- editing all files and pushing them

Replacing the .gitattributes is not possible, because when the repo gets cloned by GitHub Actions the line endings should be left untouched too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the line endings of the files which were not changed were [changed]". But note that no *existing commit* is ever affected by these rules; the EOL conversions only happen when (a) *extracting* an existing commit (Git will obey whatever rules override, e.g., from `.git/info/attributes`, at this time) or (b) `git add`-ing files in preparation for a *new* commit (Git will again obey the rules in effect during the add). The tricky part here is that the files you see and work with, in your working tree, can be adjusted during step (a).

Comment: I mean that even after I removed and cloned the repo, the EOL conversions where still performed on files which where not changed after i committed the .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disable EOL conversions for all files by adding the following line to .gitignore:

```
* binary
```

I still dont understand why `* text=false` was not enough, but at least it is working now.

Comment: The `text=false` setting is the same as not setting anything at all. To declare that a file is not text, you need `-text`. (I'm not fond of this particular complication of `.gitattributes` values - I just got it wrong initially, it's `-text` not `!text`.) The `binary` macro is equivalent to `-text -diff -merge`.